# how to get back data from navigation properties from a many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, many-to-many, anonymous-function

This is Neighbourhood class, a neighbourhood can have many followers:

```
public class Neighbourhood
{
    public Neighbourhood()
    {
    this.Followerss = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();     
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NeighbourhoodName { get; set; }
  //Calculated property
  public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Followerss { get; set; }
 }
```

and this is my ApplicationUser class, a user can follow multiple neighbourhood:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole,>
 { 
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public ApplicationUser()
   {
     this.Followings = new HashSet<Neighbourhood>(); 
    }
   public virtual ICollection<Neighbourhood> Followings { get; set; }
```

Now, these two have many to many relationship with each other so, it created a new table in database named NeighbourhoodApplicationUsers with column (Neighbourhood_Id and ApplicationUser_Id).

Now, i want to have a method which would return back followers of Neighbourhood So,i have written this:

```
   public virtual IEnumerable<NeighbourhoodProfileModel> GetFollowers(int userId)
    {
        var profiles = _context.Neighbourhoods
            .SelectMany(u => u.Followerss)
            .Select(u => new NeighbourhoodProfileModel
            {
                NeighbourhoodId = u.,
                NeighbourhoodName = u.,
                followersCount = u.,
                IsFollowed = u.Followings.Any(user => user.Id == userId),
            }).ToList();
        return profiles;
    }
```

I dont know how to model this anonymous function here, I am stuck here, i think may be i am doing it wrong way. putting (.)dot after u, it should return u.NeighbourhoodName something like that but it returning back data related to user, not getting data related to neighbourhood class.

**If i comment out line .SelectMany(u => u.followerss) then i get all the required properties in anonymous function.**

This is my view model :

```
public class NeighbourhoodProfileModel
 {
    public int NeighbourhoodId { get; set; }
    public string NeighbourhoodName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int postCount { get; set; }
    public int followersCount { get; set; }
    public int Followerss { get; set; }
    public bool IsFollowed { get; set; }
 }
```

Please suggest me how to modify GetFollowers method to return back correct data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it works like expected, `SelectMany` takes the collection of `Applicationusers` from every `Neighbourhood` and puts them all together in a list, so when you project them you will get the properties of `ApplicationUser`.

Secondly what you are trying to do is just not possible, you have a many-to-many relationship, so by definition every `Applicationuser` can have multiple `Neighbourhoods`, how could you expect to find **one** neighbourhood per application to get the id and name etc? I think the relationship you're looking for is one-to-many, every neighbourhood can have multiple applicationusers, but every applicationuser has only one neighbourhood. That would give you the expected behavior when you project the users into `NeighbourhoodProfileModel`.

So your `ApplicationUser` model would look like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin,CustomUserRole,>
{ 
  public string Address { get; set; }

  public virtual Neighbourhood NeighbourHood { get; set; }  
}
```

If Applicationuser really needs multiple neighbourhoods, you can also opt to use `Select` instead of `SelectMany`. This will create a list of lists of applicationuser per Neighbourhood. Then the projection should be possible.

And you don't need the intermediate table. You would also need to add the primary key of `Neighbourhood` to your `ApplicationUser` as a property together with a `ForeignKey` attribute. (Unless you choose for fluent mapping which would be even better).

(By the way, since you're projecting into `Neighbourhoodprofilemodel` you don't have an anonymous function, that would be the case if you had `.Select(u => new {})`